# How to display my plot in the graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hello I have a problem with my python code. I want to create a plot and for that I have a button and what I want is when I click on the button I get the plot on the graph that I want. And now what I get is a plot but on the button !

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class Index(objects):
    ind = 0
    def next(self,event):
        a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
        b = np.array([15,20,1,3,5])
        v = plt.plot(a,b)


callback = Index()
axnext = plt.axes([0.0, 0.90, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Plot')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: should `class Index(objects)` be `class Index(object)` instead?

Comment: making that change does plot it, but it plots inside the button? I'll keep going and see if I can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I've fixed it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

figure, ax1 = plt.subplots()

class Index(object):

    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):    
        a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
        b = np.array([15,20,1,3,5])
        ax1.plot(a,b)


callback = Index()
axnext = plt.axes([0.0, 0.90, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Plot')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

plt.show()
```

So here I've changed `class Index(objects)` to `class Index(object)`. I've also defined a figure and some simple axis before the class, this means that you can draw to that figure. Without that it seems to draw your graph inside the 'Plot' button.